# Getting MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of Object while parsing JSON to result object

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I want to parse an XML file with configuration properties to JSON and after all cast this JSON to the final result object.

My class looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class AdvancedApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    SpringApplication.run(AdvancedApplication.class, args);

    XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    try {
      List XMLEntries = xmlMapper
          .readValue(new ClassPathResource("configuration.xml")
              .getFile(), List.class);

      ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
      String jsonConfig = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(XMLEntries);

      JsonNode parent = new ObjectMapper().readTree(jsonConfig);
      String content = parent.path("serverport").asText();

      System.out.println(content);

      System.out.println(jsonConfig);
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }

}
```

In first scenario:

```
List XMLEntries = xmlMapper
          .readValue(new ClassPathResource("configuration.xml")
              .getFile(), List.class);
```

above approach wraps JSON in the list with a result like:

```
[ {
  "serverport" : "9966"
}, {
  "clientport" : "9999",
  "serverHost" : "localhost"
} ]
```

but in this case I cannot read a value with the line:

```
String content = parent.path("serverport").asText();
```

because content is empty.

Finally, I decided to cast my JSON to the result object Config in this particular way:

```
Config configObject = mapper.readValue(jsonConfig, Config.class);
```

but unfortunately, I am receiving an exception like:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.javase.advanced.config.Config` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)"[ {
  "serverport" : "9966"
}, {
  "clientport" : "9999",
  "serverHost" : "localhost"
} ]"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

My configuration.xml file looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <server serverport="9966"/>
  <client clientport="9999">
    <serverHost>localhost</serverHost>
  </client>
</config>
```

And the config class as follows:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Config {

  private Server server;
  private Client client;
}
```

Server.class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Server {

  @JsonProperty("serverport")
  private String serverPort;

}
```

Config.class

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client {

  @JsonProperty("serverHost")
  private String serverHost;

  @JsonProperty("clientport")
  private String clientPort;
}
```

All I want to achieve is parsing a configuration.xml file to JSON and cast it to the Config object to create a configuration class for further usage.

EDIT:

After `@pvpkiran` suggestion I tried approach like:

```
      Config configValue = xmlMapper.readValue(new ClassPathResource("configuration.xml")
          .getFile(), Config.class);
```

but after all I am receiving an error like:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "serverport" (Class com.javase.advanced.server.Server), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: C:\Users\mzawadzki\Desktop\advanced\target\classes\configuration.xml; line: 3, column: 30] (through reference chain: com.javase.advanced.config.Config["server"]->com.javase.advanced.server.Server["serverport"])
```

EDIT2:

After modification my classes looks like:

Client.class

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Client {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "clientport")
  private String clientPort;
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serverHost")
  private String serverHost;

}
```

Server.class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Server {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serverport")
  private String serverPort;
}
```

I created a wrapper for my config class like to rid off `[` and `]` occurence.

```
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "config")
public class ConfigWrapper {
  private Config[] configurations;
}
```

Now my config class looks like:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Config {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serverport")
  private Server server;
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "client")
  private Client client;
}
```

but again that did not solve a problem and after all I am receiving exception:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "server" (Class com.javase.advanced.config.ConfigWrapper), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: (through reference chain: com.javase.advanced.config.ConfigWrapper["server"])
```

I will be grateful for a suggestion on how to reach a goal and rid of this exception.

Comment: why can't you directly transform xml to config object. why do you want to parse to json first?

Comment: @pvpkiran
good point, I thought that conversion XML -> JSON -> Object will work but that did not bring desirable effect. I tried your approach but with another exception as a result.

Comment: you are using json annotations. Now since u r converting xml to java directly u need to use xml annotation. Use `@XmlAttribute` instead of `@JsonProperty`

Comment: @pvpkiran I applied changes but that bring different exception...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution of `pvpkiran` solved a problem but I couldn't stand the fact that Jackson was not able to parse XML to a single object. The investigation brings a desirable effect and finally turned out that I had two similar dependencies like  `jackson-databind` and `jackson-xml-databind` in my pom.XML. Turns out that there is a conflict between them. After comment out `jackson-xml-databind` everything works perfectly.

Now my classes look like:

Client.class

```
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class Client {

  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "clientport")
  private String clientPort;
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serverHost")
  private String serverHost;

}
```

Server.class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Setter
public class Server {
  @JacksonXmlProperty(localName = "serverport")
  private String serverPort;
}
```

Config.class

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "config")
public class Config {

  private Server server;
  private Client client;
}
```

Thanks again for a commitment.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. You can use JAXB for unmarshalling. Do read up about JAXB. Also do notice how `XmlElement` and `XmlAttribute` is used.

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\n" +
                "<config>\n" +
                "  <server serverport=\"9966\"/>\n" +
                "  <client clientport=\"9999\">\n" +
                "    <serverHost>localhost</serverHost>\n" +
                "  </client>\n" +
                "</config>";

JAXBContext jaxbContext;
 try
   {
      jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Config.class);
      Unmarshaller jaxbUnmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
      Config config = (Config) jaxbUnmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(xmlString));
      System.out.println(config);
   }catch (JAXBException e){
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Config class will be like this

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "config")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.PROPERTY)
public class Config {
    public Server server;
    public Client client;

    public Config() {
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return client;
    }

    public void setClient(Client client) {
        this.client = client;
    }
}
```

Server class

```
public class Server {
    @XmlAttribute(name = "serverport")
    public String serverPort;
}
```

Client class

```
public class Client {

    @XmlAttribute(name = "clientport")
    public String clientPort;

    @XmlElement
    public String serverHost;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine but I was stubborn and I didn't give up. I had to find out why this devilry, simple parser not works as it supposes. Finally found a source of a problem. I had two dependencies responsible for jackson-databind. First was `jackson-databind` with version 2.9.8 but the second one `jackson-xml-databind` with version 0.6.2 which was a pain in the neck. After comment out the second one everything starts working perfectly. Thank you so much for your commitment.